# Writing spring data repository for polymorphic entity - InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Hello I have the following example:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "EVENT_TYPE")
abstract class BaseEvent {
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ACCEPT_EVENT")
class AcceptEvent {

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CANCEL_EVENT")
class CancelEvent {

}
```

I would like to write a repository for this Polymorphic entity. The thing is that I may have many EventTypes so I would prefer If I don't have to write One Repository class per Event Type. I was hoping that #{#entityName} can be applied in a generic repository like this:

```
interface EventRepositort<T> extends CRUDRepository<T> {

   @Query(select e from #{#entityName} e where e.completionDate is null)
   public T findIncompleteEvents();
}
```

I was hoping that if I have a service and I inject the repository with specific generic type it will figure out what the #{#entityName} so I did the following:

```
@Service
class EventService {
  @Autowire
  private EventRepository<AcceptEvent> acceptEventRepo;

  public runUnfinishedEvents() {
      List<AcceptEvent> unfinishedEvents = acceptEventRepo.findIncompleteEvents();
  }
}
```

It apears though that even though I have defined what the generic type is on the event repository the method findIncompleteEvents is not able to resolve the generic declaration with #{#entityName} basicly it returns both the CancelEvent and the AcceptEvent

Now my question:

Is there a way to express what I want without writing 10 different reposities for each subclass of the BaseEvent ?

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/spring-el-generic-repository.html

Comment: Also as covered in the official docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.7.x/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions

Comment: There they use concrete implementation of repository for each subclass. Exactly the oppsite of What i want.

Comment: If it could done more easily then I guess they would have documented that.Creating an empty interface for each class is hardly a great hardship given the  functionality you get for free.

Comment: But if i have 8 subclases i need to inject 8 different repositories. Of course i dont need all of them at once, but What if i want to work wit 3-4 different states? Cancel, reject, create ,confirm?? I need to inject 4 different repos ? Realy ?

Comment: I find it much more convinient to use one repository with 8 Finder methods then polymorhism here.

Comment: If you have an inheritance hierarchy that's likely to change along with the problem domain requirements then you probably have a poor design and are using inheritance improperly. You should look at different design options, for example the decorator pattern can be used to address issues like this.

Comment: I dissagree, Events are very good example on something that can be extended in trghe future. You can start with one set of events at one point new feature request comes suddenly you have a new event.